# Why does Swift NumberFormatter require a non-breaking space to work properly?

Tags: swift, foundation, nsnumberformatter, numberformatter

I have a **UITextField** with a mask formatting my input to the BRL currency, so input **1700**  from keyboard results in **R$ 1.700,00** text, but since I need this value as double, **NumberFormatter** was used like this:

```
var currencyFormatter: NumberFormatter {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "pt_BR")
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    return formatter
}
```

But when I tried to convert to NSNumber it gives me nil.

```
let input = "R$ 1.700,00"
currencyFormatter.number(from: input) // prints nil
```

Oddly, the converter works when a number is provided, and the string result can be converted to a Number.

```
let string = currencyFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(1700.00)) // prints "R$ 1.700,00"
currencyFormatter.number(from: string) // prints 1700.00
```

I started to investigate and find out what the difference is between my input and the resulting currencyFormatter string from the code below.

```
let difference = zip(input, string).filter{ $0 != $1 } // Prints [(" ", " ")]
```

It may look the same but **currencyFormatter** generates a string with a [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) after the currency symbol while my input has a normal space. Replacing my input space with a non-breaking space makes the formatter work properly.

```
let nonBreakingSpace = "\u{00a0}"
let whitespace = " "
var convertedInput = "R$ 1.700,00".replacingOccurrences(of: whitespace, with: nonBreakingSpace) // prints R$ 1.700,00 or R$\u{00a0}1.700,00

currencyFormatter.number(from: convertedInput) // Now it works and prints 1700.00
```

Finally my question is, why does NumberFormatter with a currency numberStyle only work with a non-breaking space in this scenario?

Comment: I cannot tell you why, but adding `formatter.isLenient = true` makes the conversion work in my test.

Comment: I can't find any documentation on why it inserts any kind of whitespace between the currency symbol and the numeric value.

Comment: Inserting a non-breaking space in the number-to-string conversion makes some sense, as it prevents the resulting string from being split across lines in multi-line text. *Expecting* a non-breaking space in the string-to-number conversion makes no sense to me. I have no idea if that is documented and/or to be expected.

Comment: @MartinR Interesting, I did the test in currencies which the currency symbol comes before the digits(like Bolivian Bolívar and Brazilian Real)  and it worked, but I have no idea why either, isLenient property documentation seems pretty vague about it.

Comment: My guess is that without lenient mode, NumberFormatters require that the output of `string(from:)` and the input to `number(from:)` have to match exactly. As Martin says, using a non-breaking space makes sense so the whole currency string doesn't get split between lines. With `isLenient = true`, the formatter is willing to overlook the difference between breaking and non-breaking space.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/124911

Comment: `!=` is already a function so you don’t need to make a new closure out of it.

Comment: @Jessy posted to wrong question?

Comment: @matt no he was referring to `.filter { $0 != $1 }` that can be written as `.filter(!=)` which I hadn't thought of myself so that was a cool tip. Thanks Jessy.

Comment: @MartinR you should post your `isLenient = true` trick as an answer, along with the link Matt posted, where Quinn (The Eskimo) talks about number formatters being focused on display, and subject to change over time.